# Laravel Check If Cache Tags exist

Tags: php, laravel, caching, redis

i want to check if laravel cache tag exist. how can i do that.

this is how to get cache item but how can you validate if a cache tag exist.

```
$john = Cache::tags(['people', 'artists'])->get('John');

$anne = Cache::tags(['people', 'authors'])->get('Anne');
```

Comment: Use `isset()` function: `isset(Cache::tags('my_tag')->get('my_prop'))`

Answer (score 3):

i know its an older question but you can simply do:

```
Cache::tags(['people', 'artists'])->has('John');
```

this will check if a key of John exists in tags people or artists.

Answer (score 0):

If **$john** is false, null or '' it won't pass the if statement

```
if ($john) {
    // It has valid data
}
```

or you can check for an empty object/collection using:

```
$john->isEmpty();
```

also u can check with count() method using :

```
if ($jhon->count()) {
    // do something
}
```